# some questions about begining node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, localhost, wampserver

i'm did starting learn Node.js. Formerly i used PHP and used Wampserver as local server. Now, when i starting learn Nodejs, some questions appear in my mind;

- i'm starting use terminal windows first time and i don't know how i use this method on for example a linux based server i lease. Would you instruct me about this?
- should i install wampserver for database in my computer? or have another Nodejs solution? Which is more advantageous?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Learn about Bash and databases.

Comment: You can use Nodejs on windows and you do not need wamp to work with MySQL, just install the db you want. But I'm afraid your question is way too broad on SO.

Comment: Thank for your comment. Do you have a database that you suggest? @TGrif

Comment: The choice of the db depends on the app you want to do. It's really up to you, as part of the job, to make that decision.

Answer (score 1):

If you are learning Node it would probably be better to install something more geared to that like a free mysql database. Another good way to do it is sign up for a free Amazon AWS account, you can really get a good grasp on Node by working with Lamda and EC2.

Comment: Thanks :) But i didn't understood EC2. Can i install this database in my computer? Can i use when i'm offline?

Comment: Anytime! EC2 is an Amazon server service, so it would not be on your computer. But working it with is a really good way to grasp how everything communicates. And it is free! If you need to work offline try a simple mySQL database hosted on a local connection.